# Optimising babel's react es6 class build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

We are building library of components that is then built (with babel) into `lib` folder to be used accross various front end projects.

At the moment babel outputs following code for simple react es6 class that has div with `Hello World` text in it:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true } }); if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass; }

var TEST = function (_Component) {
  _inherits(TEST, _Component);

  function TEST() {
    _classCallCheck(this, TEST);

    return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, (TEST.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(TEST)).apply(this, arguments));
  }

  _createClass(TEST, [{
    key: 'render',
    value: function render() {
      return _react2.default.createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        'Hello World!'
      );
    }
  }]);

  return TEST;
}(_react.Component);

exports.default = TEST;
```

This seems a bit verbose, even when minified, hence this question asking about possibilities to reduce size of output even more with babel?

Comment: What is your target environment ? If it already supports ES6, you could essentially skip the babel transpilation step. Also, if you are building a library, it could be interesting to provide both an ES6 version and an E6-to-ES5 transpiled version and to let your users *decide* which version they want to use. You can check this [very helpful post by Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) on the topic.